# Run a Centos 6.7 live_cd installed on usb pen as a virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox, bootable-media

I installed a `Centos 6.7 LiveCD` on a pen drive through `UNetbootin` and at reboot I select boot options in BIOS and start from USB.

But I'd like to run the pen drive inside Windows in a virtual Machine. So I tried with VirtualBox but it seems that it doesn't find any bootable OS in the pen drive.

What could I have missed or done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Unetbootin formats your usb drive in a particular manner that Virtualbox can no longer read. Instead you should still have an .iso image file that Unetbootin used to make your bootable usb. Make a new VM in Virtualbox and once you have configured it for your distribution of Linux click on Settings > Storage > then you should see Controller IDE and below it a CD icon with the word empty next to it, click on this and then check the box next to Live CD/DVD. After that click on the CD icon next to Optical Drive Secondary Master and click Choose Virtual Optical Disk File. Navigate through the file browser to your file and click Open. Then accept your settings and start your new VM.

Comment: Thanks torchhound for the answer, I'll give a try...in the meanwhile, since I'd like to use my pendrive on different PC but also working on linux (I need to create a linux webserver locally to work on my website) in a window like if I have a virtual machine and connecting through putty, maybe is there a better way than virtualbox?...

Comment: I am unsure exactly what you are asking. Working from a different machine and using puTTy/SSH adds a layer of possibly unnecessary complexity. There are other virtualization solutions available including VMware, Xen, KVM, qemu, and Hyper-V.